# How to write multiple JSON objects from multiple dictionaries in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, file-io

Let's say that I have two dictionaries like this:

```
let dict = ["2": "B", "1": "A", "3": "C"]
let dict2 = ["K": "V","N": "1","A": "12"]
```

I want to create and write a JSON object like this to a file:

```
{
    ["2":"B", "K":"V"],
    ["N":"1", "1":"A"],
    ["3":"C", "A":"12"]
}
```

I have a swift code like this:

```
let dict = ["2": "B", "1": "A", "3": "C"]
let dict2 = ["K": "V","N": "1","A": "12"]

if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys,JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted]){
    try? jsonData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: <filepath>), options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
}
```

But this code only writes the contents of the first dictionary. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **But this code only writes the contents of the first dictionary** because there is no code written that convert both dict in desired format

Comment: what is the precise rule for building a new object based on two dictionaries? it is far from obvious

Comment: True. I searched stack overflow and other websites for my answer but i couldn't find any answer. And then I tried to modify my code based on existing answers but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required output is Array of dictionaries

```
    let dict = ["2": "B", "1": "A", "3": "C"]
    let dict2 = ["K": "V","N": "1","A": "12"] // THIS SHOULD BE ["N": "1", "K": "V", "A": "12"]


   // convert to array
    var array1 = [[String:String]]()
    dict.map{array1.append([$0.key:$0.value])}

    var array2 = [[String:String]]()
    dict2.map{array2.append([$0.key:$0.value])}

    print(array1)
    print(array2)
    // Merge both array's dictionary 
    var finalArray = [[String:String]]()
    for i in 0..<array1.count {
        var dict = array1[i]
        dict.merge(array2[i]) {$1}
        finalArray.append(dict)
    }
    print(finalArray)
```

Final Output

> Array 1 [["2": "B"], ["1": "A"], ["3": "C"]]
>
> Array 2 [["N": "1"], ["K": "V"], ["A": "12"]]
>
> Merge
>
> [["N": "1", "2": "B"],
>
> ["1": "A", "K": "V"],
>
> ["A": "12", "3": "C"]
>             ]

Also notice `dict2` you have provided. remember that dictionary does not have any sorting order. So

`["K": "V","N": "1","A": "12"]`  will be treated in  order `["N": "1", "K": "V", "A": "12"]`